# Filter partitions in window - computing event recency in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way I can emulate the behavior of FILTER (http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) in standard SQL BigQuery?

What I would need to do is:

`SELECT
    MAX(date) FILTER (WHERE event_happend = 1)
    OVER (
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY date ASC
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    )
    FROM
        ...`

In essence I need to work out the most recent date a certain event occurred prior to the date of the current row.
Column `event_happened` takes values `0` and `1` and I need the most recent date on which the event occurred (`event_happened = 1`) prior to the date of the current row.

Comment: Why not use RANGE instead of ROWS? Then you can exclude the current row's value.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Thanks for your suggestion - however I am afraid I do not quite understand how using RANGE would help me. Could you elaborate please? I also added the following to my question for clarification: "Column event_happened takes values 0 and 1 and I need the most recent date on which the event occurred event_happened = 1 prior to the date of the current row."

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I also updated the name of the date column in my question - my initial choice there was confusing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way I can emulate the behavior of FILTER?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  MAX(IF(event_happend = 1, date, null))
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY user_id
    ORDER BY date ASC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  )
  FROM
    ...
```

Comment: This will potentially give the wrong answer if there are multiple of the same `date` value in the window--see my solution with `RANGE`.

Comment: :o) `MAX(IF(event_happend = 1, date, null))` is the core of answer about `FILTER` - I have not modified anything else from the original question as exact logic expected by OP is not really clear

Comment: I agree, but the OP did state "prior to the date of the current row", so it seemed important to take that into account.

Comment: i think my focus was on `Is there any way I can emulate the behavior of FILTER?` I have edited my answer to make it clear

Comment: Apologies guys I should have clarified that the table in the FROM statement is already daily aggregated data hence ROWS is sufficient in my case but RANGE is probably correct more generally. At any rate the `MAX(IF(event_happend = 1, date, NULL))` statement is exactly what I was after and I thank you both very much for providing this. I wish I could accept both answers so I will accept the response that came first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#standardSQL
WITH SampleData AS (
  SELECT 1 AS user_id, DATE '2017-11-02' AS date, 1 AS event_happend UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-11-03', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-11-04', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-11-04', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-11-05', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-10', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-11', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-20', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-21', 1
)
SELECT
  user_id,
  date,
  MAX(IF(event_happend = 1, date, NULL)) OVER (
    PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date)
    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) AS max_date
FROM SampleData;
```

I included `user_id` and `date` to see what is going on. Note that using `RANGE` is important here--if you use `ROWS`, it may be the case that the previous row in the window has the same `date` value. By using `RANGE` with `1 PRECEDING`, you can enforce that all rows in the window have a `date` value that is less than the current one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Mikhail Berlyant works well for the question asked. I had a slightly different problem where the column being aggregated was not the same as the `ORDER BY` statement in the `OVER` clause. The aggregation function I needed was `First_value`, but it works as well with some others as long you can specify `IGNORE NULLS`. Example:

```
ColumnToBeFiltered | Value      | PartitionColumn | OrderingColumn
FOO                | APPLE      | A               | 1
BAR                | BANANA     | A               | 2
FOO                | ORANGE     | A               | 3
FOO                | CHERRY     | B               | 8
BAR                | MANGO      | B               | 10
BAR                | POMELO     | B               | 9
```

For each partition, if you want to get the first `Value` based on the OrderingColumn when the filtered column is "BAR", here is how I solved it:

```
FIRST_VALUE(IF (columnToBeFiltered = 'BAR', Value, null) IGNORE NULLS) 
OVER (PARTITION BY PartitionColumn ORDER BY OrderingColumn)
AS FirstFilteredValue
```

It will return `Banana` for each row of partition `A` and `Pomelo` for each row of partition `B`.

```
ColumnToBeFiltered | Value    | PartitionColumn | OrderingColumn | FirstFilteredValue
FOO                | APPLE    | A               | 1              | BANANA
BAR                | BANANA   | A               | 2              | BANANA
FOO                | ORANGE   | A               | 3              | BANANA
FOO                | CHERRY   | B               | 8              | POMELO
BAR                | MANGO    | B               | 10             | POMELO
BAR                | POMELO   | B               | 9              | POMELO
```

I hope it can help others.